# Module 'datatables' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am getting a module not available error when trying to load 'datatables' as part of my AngularJS app.

```
angular.module('pricingOptionsTable', ['resources.pricingOptions', 'datatables'])
    .controller('pricingDataController', ['$scope', 'poResource', 'DTOptionsBuilder', PricingDataController])
    .directive('pricingDataTable', ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', PricingDataTable]);
```

`

The module's controller is defined as:

```
function PricingDataController($scope, poResource, DTOptionsBuilder) {
```

In the index.html I have:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.js"></script>
```

I am using AngularJS 1.3.9, jQuery 2.1.3, Angular Datatables 0.4.0 and Datatables 1.10.4.

Has anyone run in to this issue with angular-datatables 0.4.0?

Comment: @dandavis nope, is a module from angular-datatables.

Comment: Where is your script loaded ..??

Comment: I mean the place of your script in the index.html

Comment: all scripts are loaded at the bottom of the body tag in the index.html

Comment: Is your script / controller javascript loaded after all the other scripts?

Comment: The index.html loads all the dependency libraries first (jquery, angular, datatables, etc).  After those it loads my application js starting with my main angular module and then followed by directives, resources, pages, etc.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution @BradyErickson? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Inigo No, I did not find a satisfactory solution for this issue.  I ended up reverting to older versions of angular (l.2.x), angular-datatables (most likely 0.3.0) and datatables (not sure which version).  Generally speaking though, we did find more success with datatables by using DTOptionsBuilder and configuring the entire table in the controller rather than mixing config there with the HTML template.  We got comfortable using fromFnPromise(), withDOM() and other options on DTOptionsBuilder as well as using DTColumnBuilder.  the rendering of HTML tables was way more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Just taking a quick peek at the module's [definition on Github](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/blob/master/src/angular-datatables.js), it appears that the `datatables` module takes a dependency on the `datatables.directives` and `datatables.factory` defined (also in the git repository). The `datatables.directives` in turn has other dependencies (e.g. `datatables.renderer, datatables.options,` etc.

I believe your best bet in getting the main `datatables` module up and running is to first load the 'leaf' scripts of datatables (i.e. the scripts that have no dependencies), followed by the `datatables.renderer` (which only has dependencies on the 'leaf' scripts), followed by the `datatables.directives` script, then finally load the `datatables` script.

So it would look something like this:

```
`<script src='/some-path/datatables.util.js></script>
 <script src='/some-path/datatables.factory.js></script>
 <script src='/some-path/datatables.options.js></script>
 <script src='/some-path/datatables.renderer.js></script>
 <script src='/some-path/datatables.directive.js></script>
 <script src='/some-path/datatables.js></script>`
```

Comment: A good idea but all those source files are concatenated into the one file in the [dist directory on Github](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/tree/master/dist).  It's that concatenated file that I reference in my HTML.